# Finding a convergent power series that dominates a certain sequence over the natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have the following exercise:

Suppose that $\{ b_n \}$ is a sequence of positive real numbers. Prove that there is a power
series $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n t^n$ which converges for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ so that
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: f(n) ≥ b_n$. (Hint: Choose $\alpha_n > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that the monomial $\alpha_ n
(x/n)^{p_n}$ is greater than $b_n$ when $x = n$ and is less than $1/2^n$
when $x = n−1$. Then prove that the series converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
and satisfies the required inequalities.)

What I have tried doing is seting $a_n = \alpha_n$ and then attempting to use the ratio test to show convergence of the series for $f$. I get
$$\frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_n} \leq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} (\frac{n+1}{n})^{p_{n+1}} b_n$$
But this bound is of no use as it includes members of a possibly unbounded sequence. I'm not sure how to go forward, and in fact doubt $a_n = \alpha_n$ is even the right choice. Would appreciate some guidance towards a solution.

Comment: You cannot take $a_n=\alpha_n$. With this choice the radius of convergence can be $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the hint told you was probably not to "choose $n\in\Bbb N$" but to choose, for every $n\in\Bbb N,$ some $p_n\in\Bbb N$ such that $b_n\le\frac1{2^n}\left(\frac n{n-1}\right)^{p_n}$ (this is always possible since $\lim_{p\to+\infty}\left(\frac n{n-1}\right)^p=+\infty,$ and you can then take any $\alpha_n$ between these two bounds, e.g. $\alpha_n=b_n$).

Then, you quote "prove that the series converges for all $x\in\mathbb R$" but you forgot to quote which series $f(x)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}a_nx^n$ you were hinted. Clerarly, $a_n=\alpha_n$ is not convenient. Let us rather choose (assuming for simplicity that our sequence $(p_n)$ is stricly increasing, which, again, is always possible):
$$a_k=\begin{cases}\frac{\alpha_n}{n^k}&\text{if }k=p_n\text{ for some }n,\\
0&\text{else.}
\end{cases}$$
Then,
$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad f(n)\ge\alpha_n\ge b_n$$
and
$$\forall t>0\quad f(t)\le\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac1{n^{p_n}}\frac1{2^n}\left(\frac n{n-1}\right)^{p_n}t^{p_n}=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac1{2^n}\left(\frac t{n-1}\right)^{p_n}<\infty,$$
since $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac t{n-1}\right)^{p_n}=0^{+\infty}=0.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does that limit being 0 guarantee convergence? I only see that it implies the n-th term of the last series goes to 0 which is not enough.

Comment: The $n$-th term is the sequence $(1/2^n)$ times a sequence converging to $0,$ hence bounded.